# Hiding an import from TypeScript "prelude"

Tags: import, module, typescript

If I try to define a class with the same name as a type which is imported automatically by TypeScript, such as

```
class Map {
}
```

then I get the following error

```
error TS2000: Duplicate identifier 'Map'.
```

What I would like to do is to be able to rename, or avoid importing entirely, the TypeScript library class `Map`, so that I can define my own with the same name.

Putting my `Map` in a module (as per one of the answers below) helps, but I still can't refer to it by unqualified name (i.e. by importing), although this time there is no complaint about duplicate names; the import simply doesn't do anything:

Suppose `A.ts` contains:

```
module A {
   export class Map {
   }
}
```

and `B.ts` contains:

```
/// <reference path='A.ts'/>

import Map = A.Map

function test (m: Map) {
}
```

In order to make this compile I need to replace `m: Map` by `m: A.Map`. Otherwise the compiler complains that I'm missing some generic arguments, because it assumes I mean the `Map` type from the TypeScript "prelude".

I feel like I should be able to define a "local" name (via an explicit declaration, or via an import) which hides any equivalently-named definition in the prelude; or, I should be able to manually disable the importing of particular types from the prelude (as I can in Haskell).

Answer (score 2):

Put your class inside a module..

```
module SomeNamespace {
    class Map {
    }
}
```

This will make your class unique from the default Map class.

Comment: Great Answer +1, I would like to mention that for `or avoid importing entirely, the TypeScript library class Map` there is a compiler flag to exclude *everything* inside `lib.d.ts` with the `--noLib` compiler flag and then use a custom `lib.d.ts`. But I would advise against using that and work around it as you have mentioned to keep life simple :)

Comment: Thanks. This works, but doesn't allow me to refer to my `Map` by unqualified name, unfortunately. Updated my question accordingly.

However, I guess I'll accept this answer if there's no way around this. (@basarat's suggestion is a bit drastic :)

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20SomeNamespace%20%7B%0A%09class%20Map%20%7B%0A%09%09Foo()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09class%20SomethingElse%20%7B%0A%09%09constructor()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Sorta%20unqulified%20reference...%0A%09%09%09map.Foo()%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D